# Rails 4 Bootstrap 3 glyphicon display square under production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, production

I use bootstrap-sass to display glyphicons, it works well at localhost under development, but after i deploy it to a server use production, it display as a little square.
I have already search for answers, they just tell me to  precompile something. But they didn't work.
This is my production.rb

```
OperationBackend::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.log_level = :info
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.assets.precompile += ["*.woff", "*.eov", "*.svg", "*.ttf"]

  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
  Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin"
end
```

I also try make config.assets.complie = true 
and do RAILS_ENV=production rake asset:precompile but they all didn't work

This problem torture me hours! Wish to got help from you guys!

Answer (score 1):

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

should help

Comment: Please explain your answer in more detail. SO exists not only to answer questions, but to teach those who find this later.

Answer (score 0):

This did it for us. The glyphicons are in the vendors folder, so this is what we had to do to get them to work.

For some reason this worked for our production environment, but not our staging. Our staging.rb file is exactly the same as the production.rb file so this is quite the mystery.

```
  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  config.assets.precompile << lambda do |filename, path|
    path =~ /vendor\/assets/ && !%w(.js .css).include?(File.extname(filename))
  end
```